# This javascript function is not working as if no output is given

Tags: javascript, html, function

```
function calCGPA() {
    let cumgp=0.00;
    for (let i = 1; i <= semNum; i++) {
        const gpaForOne = parseFloat(getElementById(`subs${i}`).value);
        cumgp+=gpaForOne;
    }
    const finalCgpa=cumgp/semNum;
    document.getElementById("meanResult").textContent = finalCgpa.toFixed(2);
}
```

I just need the cummulative GPA, can you find any error in this function?
The subs is id for various gpa and the input type is "text".

I tried modifying the function but it didn\ not change in the span in the final output, I don't know that there is problem with the code or the function itself.

Comment: `getElementById` should be `document.getElementById`

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console? That should be the first place you look when you're debugging JS.

Comment: What result are you getting instead of what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

```
function calCGPA() {
let cumgp=0.00;
for (let i = 1; i <= semNum; i++) {
    const gpaForOne = parseFloat(document.getElementById(`subs${i}`).value);
    cumgp+=gpaForOne;
}
const finalCgpa=cumgp/semNum;
document.getElementById("meanResult").textContent = finalCgpa.toFixed(2);
```

}

This should work, getElementById should be document.getElementById

Comment: There is literally no change in your answer mate.

Comment: @MOHAMEDFAIZM: There literally is.  On line 4, `getElementById` was replaced by `document.getElementById`.  If that was the problem then that would make the question nothing more than a typo.  If that wasn't the problem, please update the question to clarify what problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.

Comment: I tried but it still isn't working though

Comment: @MOHAMEDFAIZM: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  (Modern browsers have lots of useful debugging tools built-in.)  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?